# Unscrollable tableview inside scrollview

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I need to make tableview inside scrollview. 
So, when I tap to row "didSelectRowAt" called, but when I scroll tableview, start scrolling scrollview.

I use this.

```
tableView.isScrollEnabled = false
```

When I  scroll everything in scrollview it's okay, but when I tap to the tableview and trying to scroll it doesn't work.

Do you know how can I fixed it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What u want do ?

Answer (score 0):

`tableView.isScrollEnabled = false` is preventing your tableview from scrolling, remove this, to make your tableView scrollable.

And It will be much better if you share some code.